# Matlab - Add rows to table where the value in the first column determines the row position

Tags: matlab

My code ammends an existing .csv file.
It loads the existing .csv file, writes new information, then saves it again:

```
    file = directory/test.csv 

    %Load data from old table
    alpha1 = readtable(file)
    alpha2 = alpha1.Variables;
    alpha = array2table(alpha2);
    
    %Get new data
    beta = array2table(newdata);
    beta.Properties.VariableNames = {'alpha21' 'alpha22' 'alpha23' 'alpha24' };
    
    %Merge old and new data then save
    merge = [alpha;beta];
    writetable(merge,file,'WriteVariableNames',0);
```

The first column of the tables is the file number:

```
2×4 table

    alpha21     alpha22       alpha23       alpha24       
    _______    __________    __________    __________   
     1        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14   
     2        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14   

beta =

 2×4 table

    alpha21     alpha22       alpha23       alpha24       
    _______    __________    __________    __________   
     4        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14   
     5        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14
```

When merging the two tables, I want the number of the first column to determine the row position within the table yielding the following:

```
5×4 table

    alpha21     alpha22       alpha23       alpha24       
    _______    __________    __________    __________   
     1        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14   
     2        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14
    NaN or zero
     4        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14   
     5        2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14    2.2204e-14
```

Further, if the row is already populated, I want it to be overwitten.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if there are multiple input tables with the same row index? I also assume the output is a `5x4` table (as shown) not a `2x5` table (as labelled)?

Comment: Ideally they will be overwritten. I modified the 2x5 to 5x4, thanks

Comment: "Overwritten" isn't specific enough - what is the order of precedence? What is your specific problem here? Cris' comment alludes to this being too broad... do you need better understanding of indexing tables? It would be better to distil your question into an actual issue, get rid of the stuff about files (it's irrelevant) and create a [mcve] with two very simple tables (give us the code to create and test them) which are maybe only `2x2`. You are starting with arrays, why not stick with them and convert to a table at the end? This is simple with array indexing...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will apply them moving forward. This code is part of an App (uitable), producing tables with 41 columns. As you can see I tried to simplify it as much as possible. Vicky managed to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
% Simulated data
Nalpha=20;
Nbeta=25;
alpha=table( (1:Nalpha).', randn(Nalpha,1), randn(Nalpha,1), randn(Nalpha,1), ...
  'VariableNames', {'alpha21', 'alpha22', 'alpha23', 'alpha24'} );
beta=table( (1:Nbeta).', randn(Nbeta,1), randn(Nbeta,1), randn(Nbeta,1), ...
  'VariableNames', {'alpha21', 'alpha22', 'alpha23', 'alpha24'} );
alpha( randperm(Nalpha,round(Nalpha/4)), : )=[]; %discard some rows
beta( randperm(Nbeta,round(Nbeta/4)), : )=[]; %discard some rows

% Merge tables
N=max(max(alpha.alpha21),max(beta.alpha21));
varnames=alpha.Properties.VariableNames;
gamma=[ (1:N).' nan([N numel(varnames)-1]) ];
gamma=array2table( gamma, 'VariableNames', varnames );
gamma(alpha.alpha21,:)=alpha;
gamma(beta.alpha21,:)=beta; %have any values in beta take precedence over those in alpha
```